# Get user infos from facebook Profile URL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Good morning all,

I must create a site in PHP where we enter the url of the facebook profile, and then it must retrieve some information from the profile:

- The profile picture
- The name
- If the profile and verify

I wish I could do it without this connection.
What to give me a clue?
(I succeeded with tiktok, instagram, etc.) but with facebook it's been a while that I'm looking for the solution

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible for 2 reasons:

- Scraping is not allowed on Facebook, you must use the API for accessing any data
- Any user data is unavailable with the API, unless the user authorizes your App to access his data

The correct way to implement verification is to implement [login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v11.0) with the Graph API and let the user authorize your App. Btw, this still does not mean you can verify his profile url, because you will not get the real URL, not even with authorization.

Comment: Yet on this website, only with the profile link it is possible to access the profile picture, name, username and ID https://hackaccount.me/hack-facebook/

Comment: it is possible, but not allowed (see first reason in my answer, they must be scraping the data). "hackaccount" should already tell you not to use it, btw :)

Comment: I do not use it is that I too have to retrieve the information but for another project! and it is the only site I've found that happens to retrieve the information I need

Comment: But it is not allowed so you can't do that.